# I Have tried to test multiple URLs in Jmeter for Load Testing with Excel file but it is showing wrong results

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load

I have taken 1000 users at a time and ramp up period is 1 seconds.I entered URLs in the Excel  file, added path and variables for respective folder in the Jmeter.
The number of urls mentioned in the Excel are 70.
So when I did the load test in the Jmeter I can see 100 users completed but in the results it is showing number of samples are 70 which is the number of urls mentioned in the sheet.

Then whatever vitual users I have tried like 500 users,1000 users always the samples are showing as 70.

As far as I know the number of sample is the number of users.
Jmeter console shows the correct virtual users but samples are always 70.

ThreadGroup:
[image]

Aggregate Report:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You attached 2 screenshots which show nothing while you should attach 2 screenshots which show:

- [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) configuration
- and especially [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) configuration

It worth also adding [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) which normally contains the reason for thread/test stop.

And finally you should clarify why do you consider the results "wrong" and how should "right" results look like.

In the CSV Data Set Config make sure that:

- Recycle on EOF is set to `True`
- Stop thread on EOF is set to `False`

[image]

While Controller - you can remove or ensure that its condition doesn't cause premature test end.